# Highlight Repeated Names

Tags: javascript, html, django, postgresql

I have a webpage that shows a list of students being requested by teachers for tutoring. A student can only be listed requested once in reality but multiple teachers may accidentally request the same student unknowingly. Is there a way to highlight a student's name each time they are requested except for the first request? The highlighting will be used to signify to teachers that these requests are to be ignored. See attached picture for clarity.

[Screenshot of Webpage]

[image: 1]

Comment: post your code!

Comment: You asked simply "is there a way". The answer is yes. Is that all you want? No, you want more, so you have to ask for it. What do you have? In what language? What did you try? Why do you think it didn't work? You are not showing any effort here and nobody else is going to do your work for you unless they also get your pay.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged with a database, this is a database answer.  You can use a window function to count how many times before the student was present in the current data set.  If that is > 1, then you have a dup.  How to turn the dup column into highlighting is almost certainly not a database question.

```
select 
  "Student Name", 
  count(*) over (partition by "Student Name" order by "Request Date/Time") > 1 as dup,
  ...
```